# @import "bootstrap" Cannot resolve import into sass/scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

Making a small RoR application and have run into a interesting issue via importing bootstrap using the asset manager.

Very simply,

In my gem file I have

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
gem 'faker'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'simplecov'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.4.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'
end

gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

I created a custom.css.scss file and added the line:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

The issue is, my IDE (Rubymine) tells me that it cannot resolve the import of bootstrap but the file compiles and runs.

However, when is start the server, bootstrap only half works i.e. some of the styling is applied but a lot of it isn't.

I am at a loss of how to fix this unless I use a relative path + the bootstrap folder but Im trying to avoid that.

Link to the repo below:

https://github.com/Oregand/RateMyCourseV2

Comment: I decided this morning to try and use a relative pathway, just to confirm that bootstrap itself would work.

However, when I did that it seemd to make no difference to the actual bootstrap.

What I've discovered is that, the pipeline doesn't seem to be the issue, rather bootstrap itself.

Comment: Well, I would like to know if anyone found out the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a line  in **application.css**

```
*= require bootstrap
```

before

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
```

and remove

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gave me the same result as simply having the @import

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by doing something similar to what Mario suggested, but instead of

```
*= require bootstrap
```

I did

```
*= require_bootstrap
```

like the rest of the requires

and the import was resolved, despite my editor giving me a warning for the lines

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `application.css.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

[Do not use `*= require_self` and `*= require_tree` if you are using Sass.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails)